# What is the difference between the rot_star and nrotstar class in LORENE (Numerical Relativity)

Tags: general-relativity, computational-physics, simulations, neutron-stars

Im doing my final grade work about neutron stars simulations. I need to compute some simulations for different EoS. In the classes, I find two different classes:

nrotstar-> I think the n means neutron (it can mean newtonian or 'non' too) but my teacher said he doesn't have idea of it

rot_star-> the class he told me to start reading about.

After searching the documentation and source files I can't extract the conclusion about what is the class what I should use. What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is of use any more, but to me it seems like Nrotstar is New-rot_star.

If you visit the file Lorene/Codes/Rot_star/README, there the variable rot_star is said to be obsolete and the user is suggested to use nrotstar instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for not closing this question. U are absolutely right. Realized what u said months ago.